# Range of $\tan(\sin(x))$ and $\tan(2\sin(x))$

Tags: functions

Range of $\tan(\sin(x))$ and  $\tan(2\sin(x))$.

**My attempt :-**
$$-1 \le \sin(x) \le 1$$
$$-57.3^\circ \le \sin(x) \le 57.3^\circ$$
$$\tan(-57.3^\circ) \le \tan(\sin(x)) \le \tan(57.3^\circ)$$

### $$-1.5 \le \tan(\sin(x)) \le 1.5$$

By the Same approach I solve the second one.

Comment: How about you tell us what you already did, where you started and where you ran into problems. Do you know the definitions of all the terms mentioned here? Do you know the range of $\sin$ and $\tan$?

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: I have show my approach

Comment: $\tan 57.3^o\approx 1.52,$ not close to $2.1...$ Less precisely, but as a check,$ \tan 57.3^o<\tan 60^o =(\sin 60^o)/(\cos 60^o)=(\sqrt 3\;/2)/(1/2)=\sqrt 3< 1.732051.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As  $-1\le\sin x\le1$ and $[-1,1]\subset(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, the tangent function is  continuous, increasing on $[-1,1]$ so by the I.V.T., the range of $\tan(\sin x)$ is the interval $\;[-\tan 1,\tan 1]$ $\;(\approx [-1.557,1.557])$.

For the second range, $-2\le 2\sin x \le 2$, so the range of $2\sin x$ contains the interval $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, and the range of $\;\tan(2\sin x)$ contains the range of $\tan$, i.e. it is $\mathbf R$.

Comment: @CiaPan: Fixed. Thanks for pointing it!